# How can I use Kubernetes API to get the metrics of a cluster like memory in golang?

Tags: go, kubernetes, openshift

I am trying to get the cluster utilization values (CPU Utilization, Memory, File System, Network transfer, pod count) in a go program. Do we have api's to get the cluster data directly from k8s or openshift which can be called from a go program ? Or can we get the individual node data and add it up to get the total cluster utilization values ?

Executing kubectl commands using os/exec in the program is not able to fetch the values.

Comment: Why not use Prometheus for this? Prometheus is a go program itself...

Comment: K8s provides an interface for the data you describe, but you need to populate the data by running metrics-server. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/resource-metrics-pipeline/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I am trying to get the data and make an api so front end can use it.

Answer (score 2):

The Kubernetes [metrics server](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/resource-metrics-pipeline) offers all of this information via the [Summary API](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/7d309e0104fedb57280b261e5677d919cb2a0e2d/staging/src/k8s.io/kubelet/pkg/apis/stats/v1alpha1/types.go#L23-L29).

Invoking this API is straight-forward using the command line.

```
kubectl get --raw "/api/v1/nodes/${NODE_NAME}/proxy/stats/summary"
```

And from go, if you are using [client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/), this API can be invoked with:

```golang
request := clientset.CoreV1().RESTClient().Get().Resource("nodes").Name(node.Name).SubResource("proxy").Suffix("stats/summary")
responseRawArrayOfBytes, err := request.DoRaw(context.Background())
if err != nil {
    return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "failed to get stats from node")
}
```

Note that, according to the official metrics server documentation, the [endpoint will be changing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/resource-metrics-pipeline/#summary-api-source) to `/metrics/resource` in metrics-server 0.6.x.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems to work, but having some issues as I also use openshift, but openshift is blocking the api currently.

Comment: @G2code make sure you have a clusterrole for yourself or the acting service account with get permission for resources: ["node/proxy"].